# Delay function in CAPL apart from testwaitfortimeout()

Tags: capl, canoe

I have a CAPL test node that controls a GPIB power supply. This CAPL generates a signal that is modified each 3 ms. My CAPL looks like this:

```
...
testcase wavGenerator()
{
   GPIBWrite(myDevice, "VOLT", voltValue);
   testwaitfortimeout(3);
   ...
}
```

The problem is that this testwaitfortimeout() function generates a comment in the test report, and since i use this function 2000/3000 times for each testcase, I end with a enormous test report.

I have tried implementing a function to generate a "delay" like waitfortimeout() does, like this:

```
void delay(int ms)
{
   float refTime;
   refTime = timeNowFloat();
   while(timeNowFloat() < (refTime + ms*100))
   {
      /* Wait to reach expected time*/
   }
}
```

but this crashes CANoe. I have tried something like this with setTimer() functions but the problem is the same. How can I generate this delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to deal with this, using a timer, an EnvVar and the function testWaitForEnvVar()

```
on timer tDelay
{
  @EnvDelayFunct = 1;
}

void delay(int ms)
{
  int a;
  write("Wait for %i ms", ms); 
  setTimer(tDelay, ms);
  a = testWaitForEnvVar(EnvDelayFunct, 0);
  @EnvDelayFunct = 0;
}
```

Comment: testWaitForEnvVar is not allowed in CAPL Node

Answer (score 3):

One idea could be to use a timer:

```
variables
{
  msTimer myTimer;
}

testcase wavGenerator()
{
  GPIBWrite(myDevice, "VOLT", voltValue);
  setTimer(myTimer, 3);
}

on timer myTimer
{
  // your code
}
```

Alternatively you can always create a custom style-sheet (XSLT) that filters all calls to testwaitfortimeout from the report.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the comments of delay with test report filter option and untick resume on events

Answer (score 0):

Vector added on Canoe 15SP3 the function **TestWaitForTimeoutSilent(int64 aTimeout)** which is the equivalent to TestWaitForTimeout but do not write the delay on the test report :

```
// waits for 3000 ms
long result;
result = TestWaitForTimeoutSilent(3000);
```